# Light blue line above my navigation bar in android app

Tags: android, xamarin, navigation, xamarin.forms, navigationbar

i'm having a problem with an app i'm building. I'm using xamarin with Visual studio 2015 community and when I deploy my app i'm having this as result:
[image]

What I want is to match that light blue line with my navigation bar. I need to know how to do it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the status bar color.
This was a feature introduced in android 5.0 (Lolipop) API 21 and above.

To customize that color you must do this:

1. Define a color for status bar.
2. Create a theme that use that color as colorPrimaryDark.
3. Apply the theme.

Step 1 (**Resources/values/colors.xml**):

```
<resources>
  <color name="primaryDark">#1230D2</color>
</resources>
```

Step 2(**Resources/values/style.xml**):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Step 3 (Your Activity):

```
[Activity(Label = "MyActivity", Theme = "@style/AppTheme")]
```

more detail [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/material_theme/) and [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/android/appcompat/)

Answer (score 1):

The jzeferino's answer is perfect, just for your information when you are developing a Xamarin Forms Application :

1) Go to **Resources/values/styles.xml**

2) Change the value of item named "**colorPrimaryDark**"

```
<!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1230D2</item>
```

*Nota bene* : when you are using a MasterDetailPage, if you want to keep the same color and style for your status bar between master and detail pages, you have to declare your MasterDetailPage as a NavigationPage and set to false the HasNavigationBar field :

```
public partial class MyMasterDetailPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public MyMasterDetailPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        (...)
    }
}
```